# Flutter : my application stopping when i used full_pdf_viewer

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The problem is when running an app on debug mode my app work normally , but in when i release my apk " `Flutter build apk` " the app Stopped don't work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xiwV.png)
 and when i remove   `full_pdf_viewer` from  **dependencies**
the apk work normally

**this is my dependencies:**

```
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  cloud_firestore: ^0.8.0
  connectivity: 0.3.0
  url_launcher: 4.0.2   
  firebase_admob: ^0.5.2
  dio: 1.0.0
  path_provider: any
  random_pk: any
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: 1.0.2
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.2.1 at /home/asouab/programation/flutter_linux_v1.0.0-stable/flutter
    • Framework revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
    • Engine revision 3757390fa4
    • Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/asouab/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /snap/android-studio/71/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at /snap/android-studio/71/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 33.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 182.5215
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension version 2.24.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5556 • android-x86 • Android 7.1.1 (API 25) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Do you have some output to post? Any error? StackTrace? What platform are you using to exeute the application? Emulator(android or ios)? Or physical device??

Comment: First try importing latest release: `flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ˆ1.0.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the official resource about how to prepare an apk to be realesed:
https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

After that you have to declare ndk with abi filters in your `build.gradle`(app level).

```
buildTypes {

    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
        }
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
    }
}
```

or adding all filters

```
abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
```

For [reference](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_full_pdf_viewer#-readme-tab-)

Comment: work in physical device but in  Emulator (android) he show me that error :
`
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
adb: failed to install
/home/asouab/programation/mon_bac/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk: Failure
[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
Install failed
`

Comment: You have to check the architecture of your emulator device through AVD manager and then you need to add that architecture to abiFilters :)